# How to add content to the menu

Tags: posts, menus

I made my menu bar and made 2 blog posts, but when I click on a menu section (ex; makeup reviews) my post dose not show up but shows up on my homepage. How do I add a post to that menu category so that page so that post shows up in the place I want it?

**Example:** If I did a post on lipstick and wanted in makeup reviews on my menu bar.

I am a newbie this blog world and I'm not tech savvy. I'm sorry if I don't have to terms right I am new at this.

Answer (score 0):

Use Appearance, Menus in the Admin area to add menu items; create a menu first if not already there.

Then assign the menu to the site via the Manage Locations tab on the same screen. Depending on the theme you use, you'll be able to assign your menu so it appears where allowed by the theme.

You can assign pages/posts/custom links/categories to your menu on that screen.

You'll find lots of videos on the subject if you ask the googles..there are also some good 'beginner' sites: I like [www.wpbeginners.com](http://www.wpbeginners.com) (not affiliated with them). Just keep looking around on the sites or the googles to figure things out.